# Импорт wsdl. Read timed out

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

Пытаюсь проимпортировать эту wsdl схему https://www.momondo.com/Momondo.asmx?WSDL

```sh
wsimport -d d:\Work\Java\Test\src\ https://www.momondo.com/Momondo.asmx?WSDL -Xnocompile
```

Получаю ошибку

> com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; Read timed out

(если нужно, могу приложить стек)

Открываю схему в браузере и сохраняю ее на диск

```sh
wsimport -d d:\Work\Java\Test\src\ d:\Momondo.wsdl -Xnocompile
```

> [WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'soapenc:Array' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
>     line 325 of file:/D:/Momondo.wsdl#types?schema2
>
> [ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'
>     line 325 of file:/D:/Momondo.wsdl

Вопросы

1. Откуда тайммаут? Может можно как-то увеличить время ожидания?
2. Какую схему ему подсунуть для определения `soapenc:Array`?

Comment: Походу WSDL битый.

Comment: @MikhailChibel WSDL Analyzer валидирует https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/service/service/1233341212?version=1